# How can I change from Canada temporary resident to dependent?

Tags: working-visas, immigration, canada, dependent-visa

I am from India and I am working as a cook in Edmonton, Canada.

I am planning to apply for Canadian permanent residence. When I calculate my points, I got only 306 total, which means I do not qualify.

My wife works in India as a software engineer, so I will bring my wife to Canada on an open work permit.

I am confused whether or not my wife is eligible to apply for permanent residence. She has a Master's degree. Is it possible for the person with an open work permit to be the primary applicant and for me to be the dependent?

Comment: Short answer. Yes its possible.

Comment: I highly doubt that someone on an open work permit can directly convert to a PR. She would have to work in Canada for a period of time.